# function does not pass a value received through "for" loop

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop

I am creating a commands from 2 files: one have the command in 3 lines ('comando.txt') the second one have parameters (file.txt)
Commands in txt contain characteres such as (" ' and ,) that cannot set on csv or list.

As a example the command result is TEXT01:12TEXT02"LAS'5022268h'0023; for df.loc[0].

1. after open comando.txt it pass row number to paso function.
2. if it prints i = row, function receives each index row from df.
3. the instruction `for line in f1:` i values does not pass even `print(i)` above it received

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

new_text = ''

def paso(row):
    i = row
    j=0
    result=''
    # 2 - it print row number that function
    print(i)
    for line in f1:
        # 3 - ERROR is here, the unique value for i=0, never pass
        #print(i) 
        strip = line.strip()
        result = result + add_para(strip,i,j)
        j=j+1
    #The result is TEXT01:012TEXT02"LAS'5022268h'0023;
    return result

def add_para(comando,valor,j):
    if j< columnas:
        #print(row)
        comando = comando +str(df.iloc[row,j])
        return comando
    else:
        comando=comando
        return comando

with open('file.txt') as f2:
    df = pd.read_csv(f2,header=None)

filas = df.shape[0]
columnas = df.shape[1]

with open('comando.txt') as f1:
    for row in range(filas):
        for col in range(1):
            # 1 - it passes row number to function "paso" 
            regreso = paso(row)
        #print(regreso)
```

printout

```
In [44]:
with open('comando.txt') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        print(line.strip())


Out[45]:


TEXT01:
TEXT02"LAS'
h'0023;
```

```
In [45]:  df.head()

Out[45]:     0    1
        0   12 5022268
        1   13 5022269 
        2   14 5022277 
        3   15 5022279 
        4   16 5022377
```

there is not error displayed but how row number `i` can be pass into `for line in f1:`

As a example the command result is `TEXT01:12TEXT02"LAS'5022268h'0023;` for `df.loc[0]` and second command `TEXT01:13TEXT02"LAS'5022269h'0023;` for `df.loc[1]` ... etc

Comment: seems you've suffered a lot on "shadow variable", on block `def add_para, i had no idea where did `row` came from

Comment: yes I do, I have to check it, any informative link about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file object is a stream. Once it has reached end of file, any new read will return that end of file condition, unless the stream is rewinded.

So you just need to rewind the file before calling `paso`:

```
with open('comando.txt') as f1:
    for row in range(filas):
        for col in range(1):
            # 1 - it passes row number to function "paso" 
            f1.seek(0)
            regreso = paso(row)
        print(regreso)
```

With your sample data, is enough to get:

```
0
TEXT01:12TEXT02"LAS'5022268h'0023;
1
TEXT01:13TEXT02"LAS'5022269h'0023;
2
TEXT01:14TEXT02"LAS'5022277h'0023;
3
TEXT01:15TEXT02"LAS'5022279h'0023;
4
TEXT01:16TEXT02"LAS'5022377h'0023;
```

---

BTW, you wrote:

> Commands in txt contain characteres such as (" ' and ,) that cannot set on csv

That is wrong. The csv format is able to accept any characters including its quoting character or field delimitor inside a field provided the quoting character is doubled.